# html5 issue for multiple audio tags in ie9 while change current time of all the audios on fly

Tags: internet-explorer-9, html5-audio

I’m working on multi track player in which I’m using multiple audio tags and manipulating all them with javascript.
[(See example code)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/05/13/unlocking-the-power-of-html5-lt-audio-gt.aspx)

```
var audios = [];
var loading = 0;
AddNote("2C");
AddNote("2E");
AddNote("2G");
AddNote("3C");
AddNote("3E");
AddNote("3G");
AddNote("4C");

function AddNote(name) {
    loading++;
    var audio = document.createElement("audio");
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function () {
    loading--;

    if (loading == 0) // All files are preloaded
        StartPlayingAll();
    }, false);

    audio.src = "piano/" + name + ".mp3";
    audios.push(audio);
}

function StartPlayingAll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < audios.length; i++)
        audios[i].play();
}
```

when I’m trying to change `currentTime` using following code

```
function playfrom(time) {
    for (var i = 0; i < audios.length; i++)
        audios[i].pause();
        audios[i].currentTime = time; //time in seconds
        audios[i].play();
    }    
}
```

Which works well on google chrome, but creates problem on IE9.

`canplaythrough` event is already binded for all audio tags. so the browser (IE9) hangs even after all the audio files are fully loaded while changing the currentTime of audio tag using above code.

Is that any other way to do the same?

Comment: What's the problem? Specifically, what works in Chrome that doesn't work in IE9? Are there errors in the console? Do any of the tracks play? Is the problem just with setting `currentTime`? Need more details.

Comment: Hello Kevin,
Thank you for having a look into this.
Yes, all the tracks plays well in Chrome and IE9 as well. And yes, as you said there is a problem just with setting currentTime in IE9. E.X. the track is getting played right now and time on track is 0:03. But, if any user moves the cursor of track and let it say to start play from time 0:15 then at this time IE9 gets hanged. 

Also, as specified in original post that this is not the issue with buffering cause you can see in code too that I have placed validation to make sure that tracks gets played once they are buffered.

Thanks,

Comment: NOTE: i have used custom UI for audio player.

Your any help in this regards will be appreciated.
Looking forward to get the issue solved soon!
Thanks,